# Save keras model with weights to JSON file

Tags: json, tensorflow, keras

I have a keras model and i want to save it to JSON. The commonly used method is to save the model architecture to JSON then, save the weights in .h5 file.

However, i need to save the model including weights in a JSON file. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try saving manually,

```
weights_list = model.get_weights()

for i, weights in enumerate(weights_list):
    writeJSON(weights)
```